# Android: How can I make a listview wait for a variable to fill before setting?

Tags: android, facebook, listview, android-listview, parse-platform

So I have a movie trivia game that I am building.  The problem I am running into is on the main user profile page I set 3 listviews.  One for games where it is your turn, one for games that are waiting for your opponent, and one for completed games.  These list views make calls to Parse.com to fetch the game object.  In Order to fetch this info from Parse I need to provide my query with a Facebook user id.  My code calls Facebook to get the ID, but the listview adapters run about 5 milliseconds before the call to Facebook returns the ID.  When the user refreshes the page, the lists load properly, but when first running the app they are blank.  Here is the user profile activity code:

```
public class UserProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ParseLogic mPl;
    private WfoAdapter wfoAdapter;
    private WoyAdapter woyAdapter;
    private CompletedGameAdapter completedGameAdapter;
    private TicketSystem mTicketsSytem;



    String mMyFbId;
    String mMyFbName;

    int mTickets;

    ListView mWfoListView;
    ListView mWoyListView;
    ListView mCompletedGameListView;
    TextView mmTicketNumber;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        mTicketsSytem = new TicketSystem();
        mTickets = mTicketsSytem.getTickets();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
        new getFbDeets().execute(); //This is where the async task is called


        mPl = new ParseLogic();
        mWoyListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.waitingForYouListView);
        mWfoListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.waitingForOpponentListView);
        mCompletedGameListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.completedGameListView);
        mmTicketNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.numberOfTickets);

        mmTicketNumber.setText(String.valueOf(mTickets));




        FaceBookFriends.getFaceBookFriends();



         //Testing start game remove when building rest of page
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startNewGame);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(UserProfileActivity.this, GameStart.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();



        // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

        mTickets = mTicketsSytem.getTickets();
        mmTicketNumber.setText(String.valueOf(mTickets));
        populateWoyListView();
        populateWfoListView();
        populateCompleteListView();


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){}


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        //create the logout button in action bar
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.logoutButton:
                ParseUser.logOut();
                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); // this will now be null
                Intent intent = new Intent(UserProfileActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void populateUI() {
        populateWoyListView();
        populateWfoListView();
        populateCompleteListView();

        mWoyListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String goTV = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gameObjectHiddenTextView)).getText().toString();
                String score = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.woyScoreNumber)).getText().toString();
                Log.v("Clicked Object Id ", goTV);
                Intent intent = new Intent(UserProfileActivity.this, AreYouReady.class);
                intent.putExtra("Score", score);
                intent.putExtra("Object Id", goTV);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void populateWoyListView() {
      //mMfbId is the variable set by the facebook call
        woyAdapter = new WoyAdapter(this ,mMyFbId);  
        woyAdapter.loadObjects();
        mWoyListView.setAdapter(woyAdapter);
    }

    private void populateWfoListView() {
        wfoAdapter = new WfoAdapter(this);
        wfoAdapter.loadObjects();
        mWfoListView.setAdapter(wfoAdapter);
    }

    private void populateCompleteListView() {
        completedGameAdapter = new CompletedGameAdapter(this, mMyFbId);
        completedGameAdapter.loadObjects();
        mCompletedGameListView.setAdapter(completedGameAdapter);
    }


    protected class getFbDeets extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            mMyFbId = FaceBookFriends.getMyFbId();
            mMyFbName = FaceBookFriends.getMyFbName();
            Log.v("getFbDeets() ", "Is Running");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            populateUI();
        }
    }





}
```

This is the completed gave adapter:

```
/**
 * Created by Tom Schinler on 9/23/2015.
 */
public class CompletedGameAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<Game> {

    String mWinnerScore;
    String mWinnerName;
    String mLoserScore;
    String mLoserName;
    String mFbName;


    public CompletedGameAdapter(Context context, final String myFbId) {
        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Game>() {
            public ParseQuery<Game> create() {
                ParseQuery<Game> queryCreatedBy = new ParseQuery<Game>("Game");
                queryCreatedBy.whereEqualTo("Created_By", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

                ParseQuery<Game> queryOppOf = new ParseQuery<Game>("Game");
                queryOppOf.whereEqualTo("Opponent_Id", myFbId);

                ParseQuery<Game> query = ParseQuery.or(Arrays.asList(queryCreatedBy, queryOppOf));
                query.whereNotEqualTo("Creator_Score", "");
                query.whereNotEqualTo("Opponent_Score", "");
                query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
                query.setLimit(4);
                return query;
            }

        });
    }


    @Override
    public View getItemView(Game game, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null) {
            view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.completed_game_layout, null);
        }

        super.getItemView(game, view, parent);
        mFbName = FaceBookFriends.getMyFbName();

        TextView winOrLose = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.winOrLose);


        int oppScore = Integer.parseInt(game.getOpponentScore());
        int creatScore = Integer.parseInt(game.getCreatorScore());





        if(oppScore > creatScore){
            mWinnerScore = String.valueOf(oppScore);
            mWinnerName = game.getOpponentName();
            mLoserScore = String.valueOf(creatScore);
            mLoserName = game.getCreatorFbName();
        }
        else {
            mWinnerScore = String.valueOf(creatScore);
            mWinnerName = game.getCreatorFbName();
            mLoserScore = String.valueOf(oppScore);
            mLoserName = game.getOpponentName();
        }

        TextView winnerName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.winnerName);
        winnerName.setText(mWinnerName);

        TextView winnerScore = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.winnerScore);
        winnerScore.setText(mWinnerScore);

        TextView loserName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.loserName);
        loserName.setText(mLoserName);

        TextView loserScore = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.loserScore);
        loserScore.setText(mLoserScore);

        if(mWinnerName.equals(mFbName)){
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            winOrLose.setText("WIN!!");
        }
        else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            winOrLose.setText("LOSER!!");
        }


        return view;
    }


}
```

and here is the adapter that sets the listview for games waiting on the user:

```
/**
 * Created by Tom Schinler on 9/22/2015.
 */
public class WoyAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<Game>{


    public WoyAdapter(Context context, final String fbId) {
        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Game>() {

            public ParseQuery<Game> create() {
                //Log.v("var fbid is ", fbId);
                ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Game");
                query.whereEqualTo("Opponent_Id", fbId);
                query.whereEqualTo("Opponent_Score", "");
                query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
                query.setLimit(4);
                return query;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View getItemView(Game game, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null) {
            view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.waiting_on_you_layout, null);
            Log.v("WOY is this", "running");
        }

        super.getItemView(game, view, parent);

        ProfilePictureView friendPic = (ProfilePictureView) view.findViewById(R.id.woyFbPic);
        String friendId = game.getCreatorId();
        if(friendId != null){
            friendPic.setProfileId(friendId);
        }

        TextView oppName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.woyNameText);
        oppName.setText(game.getCreatorFbName());

        TextView oppScore = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.woyScoreNumber);
        oppScore.setText(game.getCreatorScore());

        TextView GOTV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.gameObjectHiddenTextView);
        GOTV.setText(game.getObjectId());


        return view;
    }
}
```

I set mMyFbId with a Facebook method like this:

```
mMyFbId = FaceBookFriends.getMyFbId();
```

but it return about 1 second after the code runs to build the lists views, since they do not have the variable, they populate nothing.  Please help.

Comment: show dialog with progress bar till your data id loaded

Comment: That worked!  It amazes me how simple things get missed.  Thank you so much!

Comment: you welcome :) if it worked you can hit useful to my post

Comment: I do not see a way to do that.  I looked as soon as it worked for me.  I want to ensure you get recognized.

Comment: when you hover on comment at left side it you will see a upvote and flag..upvote is to declare that a comment is useful..